# Unable to create domain-based bucket even after verification

Tags: google-cloud-storage

My account has access to the Google Webmaster Tools for the top level domain, and I've also verified the subdomain as well as sub-subdomain, but when I try to create a new bucket with any of the domains I've supposedly verified, I get "The bucket you tried to create is a domain name owned by another user."

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Just got owner permission for the domain in WHT... still can't create the domain.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the account creating the bucket is different than the account that owns the domain. Does your personal account own the domain? If so, how are you authorizing against Google Cloud Storage? Are you perhaps using a service account? It's very easy to find yourself using a service account instead of your actual account. For instance, if you are using gsutil from a GCE instance and are using the default credentials, that would authorize you as the service account associated with that project and not yourself.

If this is the case, you could fix this in a couple of ways. Either add the service account as an owner in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/), or switch out which account gsutil is acting as (see the "gsutil config" command).

Comment: I've been delegated ownership access in Webmaster Tools, and I'm trying to create the bucket via the Developers Console logged into the same account that has been delegated ownership access of the domain.

Comment: I had another thought. Is it possible that the subdomains don't match? Perhaps you own the domain "www.example.com" and are trying to create an "example.com" bucket, or the reverse?

Comment: I'm a delegated owner of the domain (no www), and I have verified the subdomain, as well as the actual domain I'm trying to use (sub-subdomain). I cannot create a bucket with any of the (sub)domains.

Comment: Could you send an email to gs-team@google.com with a summary of your problem and the email address you're using as well as the bucket name you are trying to create?

Comment: I've sent the email through.

Comment: Hi Chendo, I've taken a look and nothing seems amiss. Your account definitely owns that site. Do you see this error if you try to create the bucket from the cloud console (console.developers.google.com)?

Comment: Yeah, I see it when I create it from the cloud console.

Comment: And, sorry, this is probably a dumb question, but just to make sure, did you log in with that same email address, or did you log in with a gmail account or some such?

Comment: I logged in with the same email address. I got an email from gs-team saying that it currently only checks for the actual owner of the domain, not delegated ownership. That said, I validated the subdomains with my own account so I figure that should work...

Comment: Is creating a bucket by delegated owner still not supported ? I am running into the same issue as Chendo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and what seemed to solve it is using the same credentials you are using to try and create the bucket to re-verify the domain.

[See the site verification API](https://developers.google.com/site-verification/)