# Recreating a deleted domain-based bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I accidentally deleted a colleague's Google Cloud project which contained a domain-based bucket, ex. www.foo.com. My colleague ignored the warning that the project is scheduled for deletion and so the project was deleted.

We want to recreate the bucket but we get the

```
Another bucket is already named www.foo.com. Bucket names must be unique
across all projects in Cloud Storage. Please choose a different name and
try again.
```

error message.

I read [Unable to create domain-based bucket even after verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591916/unable-to-create-domain-based-bucket-even-after-verification) and tried to reverify the domain in the hopes that it may lead to a fix.

After verification (domain is registered through Google and verification was repeated using a DNS TXT record), we are still unable to re-create the bucket.

I added a CNAME record to see if the bucket is still there and sure enough a page loaded with the 'Your Google account is not currently enabled for this operation.' pointing me to the billing page for the account.

I cannot figure out how to delete the bucket if the project it was in is deleted already.

I've double checked to ensure billing is enabled, the domain is verified, and that no project that either of us own contains the bucket name in question.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: It may be too late, but I would suggest contacting Google Cloud support to see if you can recover your project.

Comment: I don't have a paid support package otherwise I would have already.

Comment: Having the same problem... Was finally solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is most likely still pending deletion, which can take about a month to process. You could however restore the original project from the [resource manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager) page if you’re not willing to wait that long. Select “Resources pending deletion” and you can restore the original project from a drop-down menu.